# DatePickerTextBox white background on disable

Tags: wpf, datepicker

The following is my styling for a WPF DatePicker:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="brdBackground"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="brdBackground" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#858ca0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#303e66" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When the DatePicker is enabled it looks exactly how I want it to:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/enabled.jpg/

However, when the DatePicker is disabled the background of the DatePickerTextBox contained within it goes white:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/disableda.jpg/

I don't want the DatePickerTextBox to change in anyway when the DatePicker becomes disabled. The DatePicker's opacity is set to 0.5 when it's IsEnabled property is set to false and this is all I want to happen. Given that I'm using a control template and I'm overriding the default style of the DatePickerTextBox I'm starting to think that it's not actually the DatePickerTextBox that is being set to white but something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not go white, it actually goes semi-transparent white (A5FFFFFF) :-)

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215.aspx

now it your case, the template you copy/pasted is not the one from your DatePicker, it is actually the one from the DatePickerTextBox that it contains. But the graying is not done there, it is done in the DatePicker itself, specifically here:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                         To="1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

to prevent this, you have to edit the DatePicker's template and change one of the following:

- either the background color of the `PART_DisabledVisual` element to Transparent
- or remove the StoryBoard shown in the code above from the template altogether.

Comment: Or change `To` value lower, like 0.1